# Dynamically call getJSON inside $.when block

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, getjson, .when

Is there some way to rewrite this in less lines of code, by making it dynamic instead of doing multiple similar calls with different indexes?

```
var input = getInput();
var URL = getEndpointURL();
var results = [];
        $.when(
            $.getJSON(URL+input[0], function (data,status) {
                results[0] = data;
            }),
            $.getJSON(URL+input[1], function (data,status) {
                results[1] = data;
            }),
            $.getJSON(URL+input[2], function (data,status) {
                results[2] = data;
            }),
            $.getJSON(URL+input[3], function (data,status) {
                results[3] = data;
            }),
            $.getJSON(URL+input[4], function (data,status) {
                results[4] = data;
            }),
        ).then(function() {
            processResults(results);
        });
```

Comment: If possible I would suggest you avoid the problem you have of reducing the amount of JS code (and simultaneous requests) by changing the endpoint to receive all data in a single request. This will massively cut down the network traffic and make the server perform better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `input` is an array you can `map()` the array to request promises and use `Promise.all()` on that array.

```js
const URL = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/',
      input = [3, 5, 6];
  
const requestPromises = input.map(function(inp) {
    return $.getJSON(URL + inp);
});

Promise.all(requestPromises).then(processResults)

function processResults(data) {
  console.log(data)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```